# Use jQuery selectors in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

after a hours of searching I couldn't find the what would be the right syntax or a way to use jQuery selectors in Ajax response (could be anything)? I just can't figure it out even though I know it's super easy.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"my needed link",
    type: "GET"
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
        var pp = $(data).('.mtext').eq(5).text();
        console.log(pp);
    }
});
```

I tested using console and everything works perfectly.

```
var pp = $('.mtext').eq(5).text()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `.find()`

```
var pp = $(data).find('.mtext').eq(5).text();
```